# how to create a loop to open specific file and save to specific tab for each loop

Tags: vba

I am trying to create a loop to open specific file and save to specific tab for each loop.

loop 1, open file1 then save to sheet1

loop 2, open file2 then save to sheet2

loop 3, open file3 then save to sheet3

But code below is doing looping nine times.

Loop1, open file1 then save to sheet1

Loop2, open file2 then save to sheet2

Loop3, open file3 then save to sheet3

Etc…

```
Sub Clear_Import()

Dim daily_download As String

Dim minutely_download As String

Dim hourly_download As String

ws = Range("ws")

Dim SpreadSheets(2) As String

Dim s As Integer

SpreadSheets(0) = "daily"

SpreadSheets(1) = "minutely"

SpreadSheets(2) = "hourly"

Dim Download_Filenames(2) As String

Dim f As Integer

Download_Filenames(0) = Range("Daily_download")

Download_Filenames(1) = Range("minutely_download")

Download_Filenames(2) = Range("hourly_download")

For f = LBound(Download_Filenames) To UBound(Download_Filenames)

For s = LBound(SpreadSheets) To UBound(SpreadSheets)


Sheets(SpreadSheets(s)).Select

Columns("A:AA").Select
Selection.ClearContents

Workbooks.Open (Download_Filenames(f))

ActiveSheet.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Select

Selection.Copy

Workbooks(ws).Activate

Sheets(SpreadSheets(s)).Select

Range("A1").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Workbooks.Open (Download_Filenames(f))

ActiveWorkbook.Close


Next s, f
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are looping both the array of spreadsheets **and** files nested within each other. As the number of sheets is meant to equal the number of files, you only need to loop one array, and use the same loop counter for both the file name and spreadsheet:

```
For f = LBound(Download_Filenames) To UBound(Download_Filenames)
    Sheets(SpreadSheets(f)).Select
    Columns("A:AA").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Workbooks.Open (Download_Filenames(f))
    ' etc.
Next f
```

Regards,